# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Cart> above this Consumer<Cart> Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I put provider above material app so I can use it in every widget in-app right?
so why this error
and my code is

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ProductsProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: ProductOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen()},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this screen has the error

```
enum filterOptions { Favorites, All }

class ProductOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductOverviewScreenState createState() => _ProductOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ProductOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductOverviewScreen> {
  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MyShop"),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
                onSelected: (selectedValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (selectedValue == filterOptions.Favorites) {
                      _showOnlyFavorites = true;
                    } else if (selectedValue == filterOptions.All) {
                      _showOnlyFavorites = false;
                    }
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                itemBuilder: (_) => [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Text("Only Favorites"),
                          value: filterOptions.Favorites),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Text("Show All"), value: filterOptions.All),
                    ]),
            Consumer<Cart>(
              builder: (_, cartData, ch) => Badge(
                child: ch,
                value: cartData.itemCount.toString(),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ProductsGrid(_showOnlyFavorites));
  }
}
```

the error in the consumer is
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget
why does this screen cant know the Cart provider?
any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but your sample works fine on my end with flutter 1.22.5 and provider 4.3.2. However, I managed to reproduce your problem when accidentally importing a package named `flutter_provider` and using its `Consumer` widget. Couldn't imagine this being your problem though.

By the way, [you should avoid](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) using the `value` constructor to create your `ChangeNotifier`. Either pass a variable or use the default constructor with the `create` parameter.

Comment: thanks for your interest the problem was importing the Cart widget automatically by using alt+enter in android studio
it must be using ../